# How to rotate two objects on a specific axis independently

Tags: rigging

I want to build a very *simple* little rig to be able to turn front tires on a car model for posing/rendering.

I've set up an example file where I have two "tires" each with an empty parent. The empty is restricted to rotate on the z-axis only, so when I rotate the empty, the tire turns as desired. Each one works independently.

I then parented the two empties to a third, and set the same restrictions. However the two tires only rotate as a GROUP around a central z-axis (which is sort of what I expected).

What I want is for the empty to turn each tire along it's own z-axis, so they stay parallel - like real car tires.

How would I modify my top empty to do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can simply put Copy Rotation constraint on one empty to copy movement from another empty. And no need in central.

Comment: could you explain differently, I personally didn't understand what you have currently and what you want